Bitcoind will not run, after doing a reindex
After doing a block reindex, bitcoind will not run. I have rebooted my system a couple of times and still get the same message. 

As far as your screenshot shows, it is running fine. In what way do you observe it not running?

Normally when you run bitcoind the system starts to update with the latest blocks in the blockchain, and the terminal displays the block info.

No, bitcoind does not show anything on the terminal when it runs, it's a daemon (which means it's a program running in the background). You can make it show output if you use -nodaemon instead, and add -logtoconsole instead. But normally you'd interact with it using bitcoin-cli.

When I try using cli I get an error message: mickin@mickin-IdeaPad-3-15IAU7:~$ bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/mickin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)

I’m voting to close this question because OP was confused about the usage of the software. I does run, as pointed out in the comments. And it's not related to the reindex performed beforehand.
